# Jasmine Spec Runner: Stack Trace from failed test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm doing a little Jasmine-standalone-demo with moment.js in the src-folder.

```
describe("moment.js -> diff", function() {
    var start, end;
    it("leap year", function() {
        start = moment([2012, 1, 26]);
        end = moment([2012, 2, 4]);
        expect( end.diff(start, "days") ).toEqual(7);
    });
    it("winter-/summertime", function() {
        start = moment("2012-10-28T02:00:00+02:00");
        end = moment("2012-10-28T03:00:00+01:00");
        expect( end.diff(start, "hours") ).toEqual(0);
    });
});
```

The second test is expected to fail, and it does (diff returns 1), but Jasmine gives a stack trace, that seams pretty useless to me, unless Jasmine has an error itself:

```
Error: Expected 1 to equal 0.
    at new jasmine.ExpectationResult (http://localhost/jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:114:32)
    at null.toEqual (http://localhost/jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:1235:29)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost/jasmine/spec/MomentSpec.js:11:38)
    at jasmine.Block.execute (http://localhost/jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:1064:17)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost/jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2096:31)
    at jasmine.Queue.start (http://localhost/jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2049:8)
    at jasmine.Spec.execute (http://localhost/jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2376:14)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost/jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2096:31)
    at onComplete (http://localhost/jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2092:18)
    at jasmine.Spec.finish (http://localhost/jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js:2350:5)
```

Can someone please enlighten a unit-test-newbie. Maybe I'm doing sth wrong.

Comment: Not sure what are you looking for? You have a line number of your spec `(http://localhost/jasmine/spec/MomentSpec.js:11:38)` which should be enough in this case, shouldn't be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace is telling you which `expect()` function has failed in case you have many `expect()`s in an `it()` block.

As @zbynour mentioned, you have to go to your line 11, character 38, in your `MomentSpec.js` to find out!

Comment: Should have expressed my concern more clearly: From other testing frameworks I'm used to a simple list presenting the results. Jasmine gives me 10 lines pointing to Jasmine sourcecode. I'm simply uncertain on why this happens, as it seems completely futile to me. I even suspect to have caused an error in Jasmine. So you may choose an answer: (A) This is how Jasmine works. Don't care about it. (B) This is valuable information in most cases. (C) You have caused an error in Jasmine somehow.

Comment: Yea I agree, it would've been nicer to just say where it failed and what line, but I guess they've just decided to throw a stack dump when something's not expected